# SQL: How to take the smallest number in the row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If there are three game rounds, how do I create a logic where I can find the minimum points per round?

dataset:

| round | player_1 | player_2 | player_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 28 | 21 |
| 2 | 42 | 95 | 85 |
| 3 | 71 | NULL | 87 |

expected result:

| round | lowest points per round | worst_player |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | player_3 |
| 2 | 42 | player_1 |
| 3 | 71 | player_1 |

PS - I have SQL Server 2018. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use temp tables.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: SQL Server 2018 isn't a valid version, you might mean the version of Management Studio you use, which is just a client tool and has little to do with the database engine you connect to. Try `SELECT @@VERSION;`. As for the problem at hand, if you are using Azure SQL Database (or SQL Server 2022) you can use `LEAST`, but you need to use cumbersome workarounds otherwise. See [this tip](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7064/azure-sql-database-greatest-least-functions/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: Why are temp tables forbidden? These kinds of arbitrary restrictions are baffling to me. For the question at hand the best solution would be to normalize your database. Instead of columns for players you should have rows in a table. Then your query becomes quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

*Row Constructor* is a simplest way to achieve what is needed.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, _round INT, player_1   INT, player_2 INT, player_3 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (_round, player_1, player_2, player_3) VALUES
(1, 34, 28, 21),
(2, 42, 95, 85),
(3, 71, NULL, 87);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT _round, MIN(c) AS [lowest points per round]
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
                (player_1),
                (player_2),
                (player_3)) AS t(c)
GROUP BY _round;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+-------------------------+
| _round | lowest points per round |
+--------+-------------------------+
|      1 |                      21 |
|      2 |                      42 |
|      3 |                      71 |
+--------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Fun note: on some SQL platforms, this is called a LATERAL JOIN.  (Good interview question).

Answer (score 1):

In your question you ignored the possibility that two or even three players could share the worst score.
Here is a full solution leveraging [cross apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) and [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
select  * 

from    game 

        cross apply 
        
       (select  min(score)                                             as worst_score
               ,string_agg(player, ',') within group (order by player) as worst_players
               
        from   (select    top 1 with ties 
                          player, score 
        
                from     (select null as dummy) t 
                         unpivot (score for player in (player_1, player_2, player_3)) u
                
                order by  score
                ) u
        ) u
```

| round | player_1 | player_2 | player_3 | worst_score | worst_players |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 28 | 21 | 21 | player_3 |
| 2 | 42 | 95 | 85 | 42 | player_1 |
| 3 | 71 |  | 87 | 71 | player_1 |
| 4 | 11 | 33 | 11 | 11 | player_1,player_3 |
| 5 | 22 | 22 | 22 | 22 | player_1,player_2,player_3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a21b8755a5c45ce59b8a0c648f65d337)

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of VALUES ([Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
    num_round INT,
    player_1 INT,
    player_2 INT,
    player_3 INT
)

INSERT INTO #test
(num_round, player_1, player_2, player_3)
VALUES
(1, 34, 28, 21),
(2, 42, 95, 85),
(3, 71, NULL,87)


SELECT 
        num_round,
        (select MIN(v) from (values (player_1), (player_2), (player_3)) as value(v) ) as min_score
        FROM #test
```

Comment: That's just plain sharp.  Very slick. Even though my answer isn't as elegant, I am going to leave it in case it is valuable to someone down the line.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this through the use of UNPIVOT and windowing functions.  I used a temp table to create the values. You would reference your own table.  The UNPIVOT function is widely underused.  If I were you, I would select from the CTE so that you understand what is happening.

```
CREATE TABLE #scores (
    num_round INT,
    player_1 INT,
    player_2 INT,
    player_3 INT
)

INSERT INTO #scores
(num_round, player_1, player_2, player_3)
VALUES
(1, 34, 28, 21),
(2, 42, 95, 85),
(3, 71, NULL,87)

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT num_round, player_score
    FROM
    (
      SELECT num_round, player_1, player_2, player_3
      FROM #scores
    ) AS x
    UNPIVOT 
    (
      player_score FOR scores IN (player_1, player_2, player_3)
    ) AS up
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    num_round, 
    MIN(player_score) OVER (PARTITION BY num_round) AS minimum_score
FROM cte
```

Answer (score -1):

This code may work for you.

```
    SELECT _round, CASE WHEN player_1<player_2 AND player_1<player_3 THEN player_1
                WHEN player_2<player_1 AND player_2<player_3 THEN player_2
                ELSE    player_3 end as LowestValue
            FROM @tbl
```